# IE 11 failed to create file object from byte array in Angular 2

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

Can anybody tell me why IE11 is throwing error at the last line -

```
this.document = this.control.value;
  const bytes = 
this.documentService.base64toBytes(this.document.documentBlob.documentData, 
       this.document.documentDataFormat);
const file = new File(bytes, this.document.documentName, { type: 
       this.document.documentDataFormat });
```

This is working in both Chrome and Firefox.IE throws object error -

```
Object doesn't support this action.
```

Comment: IE11 does not appear to support the file constructor per http://caniuse.com/#search=file

Comment: Oops!! What do suggest then as workaround??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As IE does not support constructor of File API, I have come up with the following workaround. Hope this helps to others in future -

```
const bytes = this.documentService.base64toBytes(this.document.documentBlob.documentData, this.document.documentDataFormat);
let file: File;
try {
  file = new File(bytes, this.document.documentName, { type: this.document.documentDataFormat });

  if (this.uploader.isFile(file)) {
    this.uploader.addToQueue([file]);
  }
} catch (err) { // Workaround for IE 11
  const blob = this.documentService.base64ToBlob(this.document.documentBlob.documentData,
    this.document.documentDataFormat);
  file = this.documentService.blobToFile(blob, this.document.documentName);
  this.uploader.addToQueue([file]);
```

Comment: To keep it short for ie11 instead of "file = new File(bytes, this.document.documentName, { type: this.document.documentDataFormat });" you should do "new Blob(bytes, { type: this.document.documentDataFormat })"

Comment: what does documentService.blobToFile look like?

Comment: @Brahim-LAMJAGUAR's answer did it for me.

Answer (score 9):

Files are Blobs plus meta properties, so you can just add the necessary properties like this :

```
let blob = this.documentService.base64toBytes(this.document.documentBlob.documentData, this.document.documentDataFormat);
// and add the meta properties
blob['lastModifiedDate'] = new Date();
blob['name'] = 'fileName';
```

Then the blob is a file.

Comment: wow. It's really that easy. After 20 minutes of frantic googling, turning my blob into a file without using a File constructor is really that easy. Thanks!

Comment: @SeanKPS you are welcome, I'm glad I was able to help!

Comment: thanks man! your a lifesaver!! I like this solution than the one marked as answer. thumbs up for this :)

Comment: @ajgo I'm glad it helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me to create file instead of using file()

```
let file = <File>Object.assign(new Blob([bytes]), { name: fileName });
```