# IE 11 failed to create file object from byte array in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer-11

Can anybody tell me why IE11 is throwing error
In other browsers working only in IE getting error "object doesn't support this action"

```
let file = new File([files], newFileName, { type: Constants.FILECONTENTTYPE, lastModified: Date.now() });
                let uploadDocument = new UploadDocument();
                uploadDocument.fileName = newFileName;
                uploadDocument.fileItem = file;
                this.fileList = [];
                this.mergedFileList.forEach(fileItem => {
                    this.fileList.push(fileItem);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `import 'core-js/es6/object';` to your polyfill.ts file.

IE11 was released before ES6 so it doesn't implement the same methods for objects, arrays, dates, ... than modern browsers (ES7).

You can also import ES7 methods with `import 'core-js/es7/object';` but i think in your case ES6 is enought.

Comment: i already added import 'core-js/es6/object'; and import 'core-js/es7/object'; but still i am getting same issue

Comment: Check if you add your polyfill.ts file in angular.json

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support [`File() constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File#Browser_compatibility) and [`lastModified`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File#Browser_compatibility).

In IE, you should create a Blob object then set some specific properties with the File Name, Last Modified Date and Type to the Blob. Files are Blobs plus meta properties.

```
var blob = new Blob([files], { type: Constants.FILECONTENTTYPE });      
blob['fileName'] = newFileName;     
blob['lastModifiedDate'] = Date.now();
```

For more information, you could also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377464/ie-11-failed-to-create-file-object-from-byte-array-in-angular-2/53449676#53449676).